# How to get the AJAX request using the Selenium Webdriver in jmeter?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter

I am executing my selenium script using Selenium/WebDriver sampler and after the execution of multiple threads, the reporting is fine i.e. showing for each User and URL but I want to also show the ajax URLs as well in the dashboard reporting. How can I get AJAX Urls or requests using the selenium/WebDriver? Please see the below attached screenshot of my Test Plan. Currently, I am getting the current URL of each Sample using the **getCurrentUrl()** function of JMeter.

[image]

**Can anyone please help me how can I get the Ajax Request as well with the current Url?** *You can also see my previous question for more Information* [Unable to get the results for a particular URL after using the getCurrentUrl() function in the script](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/44333/44327).