# Unable to run the JMeter test plan on Ubuntu Server getting an error `NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jmeter, ubuntu

I am executing the Jmeter test plan on Ubuntu Server but at the end left with an error saying:

`Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/opt/testScripts/LcLoadTesting/agentsAccessTheCustomerInfo.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler`

> The whole error is:

```
Error in NonGUIDriver java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Problem loading XML from:'/opt/testScripts/LcLoadTesting/agentsAccessTheCustomerInfo.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       :
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler
line number         : 29
version             : 5.2.1
-------------------------------
An error occurred: Error in NonGUIDriver Problem loading XML from:'/opt/testScripts/LcLoadTesting/agentsAccessTheCustomerInfo.jmx'.
Cause:
CannotResolveClassException: com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler

 Detail:com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:
---- Debugging information ----
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException
cause-message       :
first-jmeter-class  : org.apache.jmeter.save.converters.HashTreeConverter.unmarshal(HashTreeConverter.java:67)
class               : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
required-type       : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapper
converter-type      : org.apache.jmeter.save.ScriptWrapperConverter
path                : /jmeterTestPlan/hashTree/hashTree/hashTree/com.googlecode.jmeter.plugins.webdriver.sampler.WebDriverSampler
line number         : 29
version             : 5.2.1
-------------------------------
```

**Can anyone please help me in this how can I resolve it so that I could successfully run the test plan on Ubuntu Server.**

Comment: yes, you can visit this link [Click here](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/q/44333/44327) where I have run the test in windows OS. From this, you'll get the test plan format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that you're using the [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) in your Test Plan and your JMeter installation on Ubuntu doesn't have this plugin installed.

The solution is to install the plugin, it can be done using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

1. Get the Plugins Manager:

   ```
   wget https://jmeter-plugins.org/get/ -O /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar
   ```
2. Get JMeter Plugins Command Line Runner:

   ```
   wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/kg/apc/cmdrunner/2.2/cmdrunner-2.2.jar -P /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/
   ```
3. Generate Plugins Manager command line utility:

   ```
   java -cp /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/lib/ext/jmeter-plugins-manager.jar org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
   ```
4. Install the WebDriver Sampler plugin:

   ```
   /opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1/bin/./PluginsManagerCMD.sh install jpgc-webdriver
   ```

Replace `/opt/apache-jmeter-5.2.1` with the full path to your JMeter installation and your test should work after executing of the above 4 commands.

Comment: First two steps go fine but in the third one I got an error saying: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.jmeterplugins.repository.PluginManagerCMDInstaller
` What can I do in this case to resolve this.

Comment: Most probably you made a mistake or typo somewhere, I cannot state where exactly without seeing all the commands output

Comment: By seeing your answer I got an idea and place the needed jars in respective folders of JMeter i.e. `/lib/ext`. And now the test plan executed but not in a way that it should be. I have print the logs for more information and I got one error from chrome driver i.e. `java.lang.IllegalStateException: The driver is not executable: /opt/chromeDriver/chromedriver
  at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:585) ~[guava-25.0-jre.jar:?]`. Can you tell me this why it's not working? If you want a seprate question for this then I will post it accordingly within a minute ??

Comment: You need to make it executable using [chmod](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) command like `chmod +x /opt/chromeDriver/chromedriver`. And looking into my magic ball I can predict that the next question will be "my browser doesn't start" so get familiarized with [Driving Headless Browser Testing with Selenium and Python](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/driving-headless-browser-testing-with-selenium-and-python) article

Comment: yes, it runs after giving the permissions using chmod command, Yeah your prediction is right too, I am running the scripts in the Ubuntu server, and it's not able to run the script using chrome driver, actually, I have set a `chrome_headless=true` in the script. and It gives me an error i.e. `org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
`

Comment: If you want to automate Chrome browser you need to have it installed, don't you? `wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` and `sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` should do the trick for you. See [Using Selenium with JMeter's WebDriver Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) for more details